# How to check Mac OS X version at runtime

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsapplication, osx-elcapitan

I am using below code to check OS X version at runtime.

```
if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10)
{
    /* On a 10.10.x or earlier system */
}
```

But this condition return false on 10.10.4 OS X. I am using Xcode 6.3.2.

[image]

According to [AppKit Release Notes for OS X v10.11](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/), It should work.

```
if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_9) {
  /* On a 10.9.x or earlier system */
} else if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10) {
  /* On a 10.10 - 10.10.x system */
} else {
  /* 10.11 or later system */
}
```

Comment: If you open up `NSApplication.h`, do you see `NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10` defined in there?

Comment: Yes. I have attached screenshot.

Comment: `false` is correct : On 10.10.4 `floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber)` = 1348 is **not** equal or less than `NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10` = 1343

Comment: @vadian According to AppKit Release Notes for OS X v10.11, It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Use `#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10_Max 1349`

Old:

From 10.11 SDK

```
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7_2 1138.23
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7_3 1138.32
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_7_4 1138.47
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_8 1187
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_9 1265
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10 1343
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10_2 1344
#define NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10_3 1347
```

for 10.10.4 Its `1348.0`(From NSLog output)

They increase decimal part for 10.10.x constant.

The workaround is to use `CFBundleVersion` value `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Resources/Info.plist` on 10.11.

```
if (NSAppKitVersionNumber < 1391.12)
{
    /* On a 10.10.x or earlier system */
}
```

**NOTE:** My OS X 10.11 build version is 15A244a. If someone have first build , Please update the value in if condition.

Answer (score 19):

Since Xcode 9.0, you can use code below.
Reference to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/index.html).

**Swift**

```
if #available(macOS 10.13, *) {
      // macOS 10.13 or later code path
} else {
      // code for earlier than 10.13
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
if (@available(macOS 10.13, *)) {
      // macOS 10.13 or later code path
} else {
      // code for earlier than 10.13
}
```

Comment: Calling @available(macOS 10.14, *) causes "layout" method to be called infinitely to  in NSTextView subclass. You need to do instead @available(*,macOS 10.14)

Answer (score 3):

So the #define for `10_10` you see there is for `10.10.0`.

If you look for older version numbers, you'll see specific `#define`'s for MacOS 10.7.4, MacOS 10.5.3.

And what is happening here is that on a 10.10.4 machine (like yours and mine), the app kit number for 10.10.4 is ***greater*** than the one defined for 10.10.0.

That is, in swift, I did:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    print("appkit version number is \(NSAppKitVersionNumber)")
}
```

And I got:

```
appkit version number is 1348.17
```

So your code is actually checking for 10.10.0 and older.

If you want to check for all versions of Yosemite & newer, you'll probably want to do something like

```
#ifdef NSAppKitVersionNumber10_11
if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) < NSAppKitVersionNumber10_11)
{
    /* On a 10.10.x or earlier system */
}    
#endif
```

which will compile once you start building with Xcode 7 (and once Apple gets around to defining the official shipping version/build number for the El Capitan release)

FWIW, the Xcode 7 beta I have includes "`NSAppKitVersionNumber10_10_3`" in the 10.11 SDK.

Comment: Xcode 7 beta doesn't have NSAppKitVersionNumber10_11. I have added my workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to support multiple systems (you can adapt method return value):

```
#import <objc/message.h>

+ (NSString *)systemVersion
{
  static NSString *systemVersion = nil;

  if (!systemVersion) {
    typedef struct {
      NSInteger majorVersion;
      NSInteger minorVersion;
      NSInteger patchVersion;
    } MyOperatingSystemVersion;

    if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] respondsToSelector:@selector(operatingSystemVersion)]) {
      MyOperatingSystemVersion version = ((MyOperatingSystemVersion(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend_stret)([NSProcessInfo processInfo], @selector(operatingSystemVersion));
      systemVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mac OS X %ld.%ld.%ld", (long)version.majorVersion, version.minorVersion, version.patchVersion];
    }
    else {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
      SInt32 versMaj, versMin, versBugFix;
      Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMajor, &versMaj);
      Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionMinor, &versMin);
      Gestalt(gestaltSystemVersionBugFix, &versBugFix);
      systemVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mac OS X %d.%d.%d", versMaj, versMin, versBugFix];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }
  }

  return systemVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Yosemite, you can use `[NSProcessInfo processInfo].operatingSystemVersion` and test the result in the struct `NSOperatingSystemVersion`.

Comment: Thank you but i am supporting 10.6 and above.

Comment: do if respondsToSelector e.g. operatingSystemVersion If not use gestalt